# Difficulty reading from a text file into a wxArrayString combo box

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am having trouble getting my text file of string names, into a drop down menu in my GUI. I Have included any relevant code. The loop and everything works when isolated in a separate file, so I am guessing it is a widgets interaction mistake I have made.
Cheers in advance!

```
wxArrayString stationsComboChoices;

std::ifstream file("stationnames.txt");
std::vector<std::string> stationnames;
std::string input;
while (file >> input)
{
    stationnames.push_back(input);
}
 
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = stationnames.begin(); it != stationnames.end(); ++it)
{
    stationsComboChoices.Add(it->c_str());
}

m_fromstation = new wxComboBox(leftpanel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxPoint(50, 220), wxDefaultSize, stationsComboChoices, wxCB_DROPDOWN);
```

Comment: what happens - control is empty or displays the wrong text? Did you debug that code?  Is the file opens successfully? Finally - usual stanza: wx version? OS version?

Comment: The dropdown combo box in the gui appears empty. The loop to read in the text file works successfully as i have tested it in another code file. The programme debugs without returning any faults it just doesnt display the names of the stations in the combo box in the gui. Cheers

Comment: what encoding is the file? Can you try the explicit conversion - `wxString temp( it->c_str()); stationsComboChoices->Add( temp );` and see what `temp` contains?

Comment: Hi, not entirely sure what you mean by encoding type, im a bit of a novice. However when i tried inputing the way you suggested into the loop it returns errors saying; wxArraySString::Add left operand has class type use'.' and wxArrayString does not have an overloaded member operator ->

Comment: I changed the ->Add to .Add and the programme complies and runs but the same issue of it not displaying the values in the GUI

Comment: can you check under the debugger what value is in the `temp`? Also, why do you want to use `wxArrayString`? Can't you just add the string directly one by one? Using that class is just a convenience wrapper around looping the array and adding the element.

Comment: Do you mean just physically write out the strings directly into the programme? I am at the stage where im considering just doing this, the only reason i havent is because there is 160 stations, i thought it would be more sophisticated to try and read the text files in etc. I'm not too sure where to look for the value of temp?

Comment: just use the debugger. or good old printf. Also, it doesn't matter how many strings you put in - like I said all you are doing is calling the function which will do the loop for you.

Comment: Hi, sorry to keep bothing you, this is just really frustrating that i cant get this to work. It returns an error saying that term does not evaulate to a function take 1 argument? would you know what that meant?

Comment: show you new code. Are you trying to add the strings one by one?

Comment: Ah perhaps but im not sure what the best way to go about that is other than just going stationsComboChoices.Add("stationnames"); 160 times. Cheers

Comment: create your combo box, open the file and in the loop: read string, add it to the combo. Check the docs for parameters. But if you need more than 100 items - something is definitely wrong. You need to rething the design. You users will be very angry for scrolling those items.